# how to store string as an objectId using loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a Loopback model of project.json

**project.json**

```
"properties" : {
 "users": {
        "type": [
        {
          "user_id": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

array of id stored string format

```
{
    "users" : [
    {
        "user_id" : "5ae319e8ac5718155ca719d0"
    },
    {
        "user_id" : "5ae31a4d770afb158ef6c048"
    }
]}
```

how to store string as an objectId like this

```
{
     "users" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5ae319e8ac5718155ca719d0")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5ae31a4d770afb158ef6c048")
        }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: you want to transform the 2nd array into the 3rd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project Model

```
"relations": {
 "user": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "user",
  "foreignKey": "id"
}}
```

In User Model

```
"relations": {
 "projects": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "project",
  "foreignKey": "project_user_id"
}}
```

If there is no relations, You can use

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var userId=ObjectId("5ae319e8ac5718155ca719d0")
```

and create into db.

You can check the type using typeof(userId). It will be an object.

Answer (score 1):

In Loopback 4 the string can be stored as ObjectId as follow:
Define this property in your loopback model file

```
@property({
        type: "string",
        mongodb: { dataType: "ObjectId" }
    })
    mainId?: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to define it as a relationship, not a list of objects. Then you can define relation like users, or members. I assume that a project has many users, and a user can belong to many projects. Then, you need to define `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship:

```
Project.hasAndBelongsToMany(User);
User.hasAndBelongsToMany(Project);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html).